# MonoGame and Windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, monogame

Is it possible to "connect" Windows 8.1 application with MonoGame? I'd like to use MonoGame as Image renderer so I could use shaders to image processing.

EDIT:
Solved - there is WinRT Xaml template in monogame - it uses SwapBackgroundChainPanel so MonoGame can be used like control template

Comment: What do you mean, "connect?"

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a Metro UI application, and have a UI element that contains a MonoGame view. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You might be able to hack something together, but it's probably not going to be easy.